# AngularJS - view is not updated from modal dialog

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to update a view upon saving data to the DB.

```
main.html

<div ng-controller='sitesController'>
    <div class='modal-dialog'>
        <div class='modal-content'>
            <div class='modal-body'>
                <form ng-submit="createSite()">
                    <label>Site Name</label>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="siteName"/>                                                                                                                                                                                            
                    <button type="submit">Save</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

sitesController.js

app.controller('sitesController', ['$scope', '$resource', function ($scope, $resource) {

    var Site = $resource('/api/sites');

    Site.query(function (results) {
        $scope.sites = results;
    });

    $scope.sites = []

    $scope.createSite = function () {
        var site = new Site();
        site.name = $scope.siteName;
        site.$save(function (result, scope) {
            scope.sites.push(result);
            scope.$apply();
        });
    }
}]);
```

When clicking the save button, the data is stored correctly in the server but the UI does not refresh (refreshing manually shows the new entry).
When moving the form outside the modal, everything works fine.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: where is the view to be updated? I see you first populate $scope.sites with Site.query() and then make it an empty array. after you push the result to scope.sites where is it reflected in the view?